# Sublime, Python, web servers and setting breakpoints

Tags: python, plone, sublimetext, remote-debugging, pdb

What's the recommended method to debug Python web servers (I have Plone/Zope) with Sublime Text 2?

- Set real breakpoints in the text editor...
- ... preferably through line context sensitive command and have a marker in the text editor margin ...
- ...then have a running Python web server (local process) instantly honour the breakpoints without restart...
- ... and when hitting the breakpoint open a debug prompt in a terminal or some other window, can be pdb

The goal is that the breakpoints would not be hard `import pdb ; pdb.set_trace()` style breakpoints as you need to restart the software to skip such breakpoint and you cannot enable / disable it run-time.

Platform: OSX.

Answer (score 2):

[mr.freeze](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/mr.freeze) provides a way to set a breakpoint in a running Zope instance without restarting, and a sample script for integrating it with TextMate (triggered via a key shortcut). It would take a bit of work to turn it into a Sublime Text plugin, but it would be a good starting point.

The sample TextMate scripts are in [the README](http://svn.plone.org/svn/collective/mr.freeze/trunk/README.txt) but not released.